# Java program not compiling

Tags: java

I have an assignment based on someone inputting their exam scores and a bunch of if else statements depending on their scores with some rounding. Unfortunately it will not compile and I have no idea why.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection;
    double listeningScore, speakingScore, readingScore, writingScore, overallScore1;
    
    System.out.println("-------****-------****-------****-------****-----****----- ");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Concordia Language Proficiency Evaluator! \n\t based on IELTS exam");
    System.out.println("-------****-------****-------****-------****-----****----- ");
    
    System.out.println("Here are the available options:");
    System.out.println("\t1 - Language Proficiency Requirements for the Applicant");
    System.out.println("\t2 - Evaluation of your language proficiency");
    
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the digit corresponding to your case: ");
    selection = keyboard.nextInt();
    
    if (selection == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("\n- The overall score of IELTS exam of applicants needs to be equal or above 6.5 and the scores" 
                + "\nfor writing and reading skills should not be below 6.0. If your overall score is 6, and your reading and writing scores are at least 6, you will be eligible for conditional admission."
                + "\nSo you need to take an English course in the first semester. Otherwise you have to retake the IELTS exam." 
                + "\nThanks for choosing Concordia. ");
    }
    
    else if (selection ==2)
        
        {
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the your listening score: ");
        listeningScore = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the your speaking score: ");
        speakingScore = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the your reading score: ");
        readingScore = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the your writing score: ");
        writingScore = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
}
        
    double overallScore1 = (listeningScore + speakingScore + readingScore + writingScore) /4 ;
    
        if (overallScore1 - (int)overallScore1 <0.25)
            overallScore1 = (int)overallScore1;
            
            else if (overallScore1 - (int)overallScore1 >=0.25 && overallScore1 - (int) overallScore1 <0.75)
                overallScore1 = (int)overallScore1 + 0.5;
                
                else if (overallScore1 - (int)overallScore1 >= 0.75)
                    overallScore1 = (int)++overallScore1;
        
        
        System.out.print("\n\t Your overall score is: " + overallScore1);
        System.out.print("\n\tYour reading score is: " + readingScore);
        System.out.print("\n\tYour writing score is: " + writingScore);
        
                
            else if (overallScore1 >= 6.5 && readingScore >=6 && writingScore >=6)
                    System.out.print("\t\n Congratulations: You are eligible for admission");
            
            else if (overallScore1 >=6.5 && readingScore <6 || writingScore <6)
                System.out.print("\t\n Congratulations: You are eligible for a conditional admission. You must take an English course in the first semester.");
        
            else if (overallScore1 == 6 && readingScore >=6 && writingScore >=6)
                System.out.print("\t\n Congratulations: You are eligible for a conditional admission. You must take an English course in the first semester.");
                
            else if (overallScore1 == 6 && readingScore <6 || writingScore <6)
                System.out.print("\t\n Unfortunately, you must retake the exam.");
        
            else if (overallScore1 <6)
                System.out.print("\t\n Unfortunately, you must retake the exam.");
                
                
}

}
```

The compile errors are

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>
> Duplicate local variable overallScore1
>
> Syntax error on token "else", delete this token at Comp248/Assignment.assignment2.main(assignment2.java:50)

Comment: What are the compile errors you are getting?

Comment: Could you quote the (first) message from the compiler. It points to a specific point in your program — where exactly?

Comment: Tip: Always use brackets

Comment: Part of it might be the `else if` immediately after the three `System.out.println` lines.  An `else if` can really only follow the line or block after an `if`.  Try putting `{ }` characters around the scope of the previous `else if`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes you can.

Comment: @OleV.V Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Duplicate local variable overallScore1
 Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

 at Comp248/Assignment.assignment2.main(assignment2.java:50)

Comment: And, on the conditions where you have both `&&` and `||`, you'll want to use parentheses to make sure the `||` gets evaluated first.  Otherwise, `&&` will be evaluated first, and I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Allison, that first error means you've declared `overallScore1` twice.  Remove the word `double` from the line where you first use it.  And I've already told you how to fix the second error.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Ok, i Changed the else if to an if, and now it says the problem is where i declare  double overallScore1 = (listeningScore + speakingScore + readingScore + writingScore) /4 ;

Comment: Are you not using an IDE? Any decent IDE will help you format your code and they are generally good at highlighting syntax errors. My IDE highlighted `double overallScore1 = (listeningScore + speakingScore . . .` because it is a duplicate local variable in this scope. It also highlighted the bad `else`. Definitely use an IDE, there is rarely a reason not to.

Comment: I know it’s mentioned twice already, put you should absolutely use `{` and `}` around **all** blocks of code. It could save you and anyone else using your code a lot of pointless trouble.

Comment: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/03/the-top-11-free-ide-for-java-coding-development-programming/

Answer (score 1):

In the 4th line you have already declared "overallscore1" and then after one if and else if, you are declaring it again. You aren't allowed to declare a variable twice in the same block. So here if you want to use the previous variable you need to write

```
overallscore1= = (listeningScore + speakingScore + readingScore + writingScore)
```

I think you will be getting one more error now "else without if error". Try this

```
 else if (overallScore1 - (int)overallScore1 >= 0.75)
 {         
    overallScore1 = (int)++overallScore1;
    System.out.print("\n\t Your overall score is: " + overallScore1);
    System.out.print("\n\tYour reading score is: " + readingScore);
    System.out.print("\n\tYour writing score is: " + writingScore);
 }
 else if (overallScore1 >= 6.5 && readingScore >=6 && writingScore >=6)
    System.out.print("\t\n Congratulations: You are eligible for admission");
```

If you want to write more than one statement for a particular case, use "{}" these.
for ex.

```
if(condition1)
{
  Statement 1
  Statement 2
  Statement n
}
else
{
   Statement 1
   Statement 2
   Statement n
 }
```